# Symmetric $N\times N$ matrix, multiplicity $N-1$, for any $N$

Tags: matrices

The $N\times N$ matrix has $1-s$ along the diagonal and $s/(N-1)$ on the off diagonal. For $N=2,\dots,5$ the characteristic polynomial is $(X-1)(X+\frac{N}{N-1}s-1)^{N-1}$ where $X$ denotes eigenvalue.

Question. Does this polynomial generalize to any $N > 1$?

This would allow me to bound $s$ generally, $s < 1/2$ and as $N$ is large $s < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The all-one vector is an obvious eigenvector with eigenvallue $1$.
The $n-1$ vectors $e_i-e_n$, $1\le i<n$ are linear independent eigenvectors with eigenvale $\lambda=1-s-\frac s{N-1}$, so the characteristic polynomial must indeed be $(X-1)(X-\lambda)^{N-1}$.